# extreme values on quarter ellipse (advanced multivariable calculus)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the extreme values taken by $f(x,y) = xy(4x^2+y^2-16)$ on the quarter ellipse

$E = {(x,y) \in R^2: x \geq0,y\geq0, 4x^2+y^2\leq16}$

I tried following the example #6 in http://math.harvard.edu/~ytzeng/worksheet/1017_sol.pdf and but I feel like I'm doing it wrong because I get a ridiculous equation. Also, when I use the determinant to find the extreme values, I end up with the test being inconclusive. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed follow exactly the same method described, and the resulting equations are not particularly difficult to solve.

Set the partial derivatives to zero and you get $x=0,\pm1$ and $y=0,\pm2$ so in the region you have the critical points $(0,0)$ and $(1,2)$ which you can investigate for max/min.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the Lagrange multiplier here is applicable. You can try that and after getting your points use the Hessian function to determine if they are max or min.